# How to convert human readable data into a timestamp (with JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, timestamp, human-readable

I am trying to build a self-depricating schedule. I'm using a framework with no calendar style module.

So I have a field, we'll call it `group date`, that takes human readable data. So `group date` could = 01/02/03. The problem is, that this isn't a time stamp, just `html`.

I need this converted so I can convert the date from 01/02/03 into `030102` so the days section is on the end. Then my if statement will do the same with the current time so I can filter by saying

> if the current date is greater than or equal to group date then don't show this item.

Yes, it's a work around but it is the only realistic way I can accomplish this, given the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use new Date(year, month, day, hours, secs) to convert.

```
converted_date = new Date(2003,01,02, 0, 0)
now = new Date()
if(now > converted_date) {
    // don't show
}
```

Comment: Will this allow me to pull a token from the input's value, or do I have to set the date within JS?

Comment: You can tokenize input by using the split-method.

    "01/02/03".split("/") will return an array